# Pass output of a command to rm -r command

Tags: linux, shell

I want to remove the old directory present in a directory when the number of the directories exceeds 10.
when I run the command,

```
sudo rm -r `ls -1t /ebs/lucene_indexes/ | tail -n +10`
```

I am getting following error:

```
rm: cannot remove â1432120954â: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove â1432120945â: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove â1432120937â: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove â1432120927â: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove â1432120917â: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove â1432118817â: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove â1432118631â: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove â1432118349â: No such file or directory
```

But when I execute:

```
ls -1t /ebs/lucene_indexes/ | tail -n +10
```

I am getting following output:

```
1432120954
1432120945
1432120937
1432120927
1432120917
1432118817
1432118631
1432118349
```

For some reason when I execute the first command, directory names are getting appended and prepended by a special character. So it is failing. Why is it happening like this? What's going wrong here ?

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is that the output from `ls` contains colour output which somewhat pollutes the arguments you're passing to `rm`. Try `ls --color=never`

Comment: Good point, @beny23 ! You can also prevent any alias from affecting `ls` by saying `\ls`.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you aren't in the `/ebs/lucene_indexes/` directory when you execute the `ls`, which means the listed directories aren't directly under your current working directory. I would `cd` into the directory and do your `ls` from ".". I don't remember any simple way to have `find` sort by time, so does

```
(cd /ebs/lucene_indexes/; sudo rm -r $(ls -t | tail -n +10 ))
```

get you what you want? Note the surrounding parentheses execute the `cd` in a subshell so your existing `cwd` doesn't change. Also, the `-1` is unnecessary in a pipe.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do this by using ssh

Comment: ++ for the diagnosis, but it's worth noting that this will break with filenames with embedded spaces (just like the OP's own command).

Comment: @AshwinG `ssh <host> "(cd /ebs/lucene ... ))"`

Comment: @mklement0 you're correct, of course, but handling all the unusual filename cases for sample suggestions such as this tends to obscure the point of the answer to the question.

Comment: I get the distraction aspect, but there are two ways to handle this, depending on how much effort you want to expend: (a) after addressing the _immediate_ problem, _mention_ that others may be lurking, or (b), if you want to be extra nice, also _explain_ how to tackle the others. P.S.: And, if you feel like doing neither (a) nor (b), up-vote comments that substitute for (a).

Comment: @mklement0 Again, you're right; I usually put in a comment about handling unusual file names. I've remedied my failure to upvote corrective comments. Thanks, :)

Answer (score 2):

`xargs` is your friend, eg.:

```
ls -1t /ebs/lucene_indexes/ | tail -n +10 | xargs rm -r
```

Cheers,

Comment: Good idea to point out that `xargs` is the right tool for the job, but note that your reformulation is in essence identical to the OP's own command, which means: (a) it'll fail fundamentally if the current directory isn't `/ebs/lucene_indexes/`, and (b) it'll break with filenames with embedded spaces.

Answer (score 1):

**[mpez0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27898/mpez0) contains the crucial pointer**: the `rm` command is not necessarily run in `/ebs/lucene_indexes/`, so, when run from a different directory, it'll fail with the *filename-only* output that `ls -1t` produces.

mpez0's answer fixes that problem, but, just like the OP's command, it breaks with filenames with embedded spaces; here's **a version that handles filenames with embedded spaces correctly**:

```
(cd /ebs/lucene_indexes/ && \ls -t | tail -10 | sudo xargs -I {} rm -r -- {})
```

It uses `xargs` to read the output lines from `ls`, and invokes `rm` for every output line (`-I`), with each line as a *single* command-line argument; the downside to this POSIX-compliant use of `xargs` is that you get *multiple* `rm` invocations.

Using GNU `xargs`'s ability to parse NUL-separated input with the `-0` option, you can **make the command more efficient** by having `xargs` pass as many arguments as will fit on a command line, resulting in (typically) only *one* invocation of `rm`:

```
(cd /ebs/lucene_indexes/ && \ls -t | tail -10 | tr '\n' '\0' | sudo xargs -0 rm -r --)
```

- `tr '\n' '\0'` replaces newlines with NULs (`0x0`), in preparation for processing by `xargs -0`.
- `xargs -0 rm -r --` passes all NUL-separated tokens from stdin as *command-line arguments* to `rm -r`, resulting in (typically) only *one* invocation of `rm`

  - Note that it is the use of NUL-separated input that correctly preserves paths with embedded spaces (or even tabs) as distinct arguments. Without the `tr '\n' '\0'` / `xargs -0` combo, with just `xargs rm -r`, paths with embedded spaces would mistakenly be broken into *multiple* arguments, causing `rm` to fail.

Paying attention to how `ls` is configured (`--color` behavior, bypassing a potential alias named `ls` with `\ls`), as stated in comments, is also worthwhile, but that brings us to a larger point: it's [generally not a good idea to parse `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), as there are usually better and more robust alternatives available (globbing, `find`).

Unfortunately, avoiding `ls` in *this case* complicates the command significantly. Read on for a `find`-based solution.

---

Note: At the end of the day, **this `find`-based solution doesn't have much of an advantage over the `ls`-based one**, given that it also won't work with filenames with *embedded newlines*; **it will however, help with filenames that contain exotic characters such as tabs (`\t`)**, which `ls` typically represents as `?` in the output.

```
find /ebs/lucene_indexes -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf '%T@\t%p\n' | 
 sort -n | head -10 | cut -f2- | tr '\n' '\0' | sudo xargs -0 rm -r --
```

<sup>Note: In the following explanation, 'file' refers to both files and directories.</sup>

- `find /ebs/lucene_indexes -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` is the equivalent of `ls /ebs/lucene_indexes`, except that it returns *paths*, not just filenames (and the output won't be sorted).
- `-printf '%T@\t%p\n'`outputs each file's last-modified date in epoch time (`%T@`), followed by a tab, followed by the file's full path (`%p`).
- `sort -n` then sorts the output so that the oldest files are listed first, and `head -10` therefore outputs the 10 oldest files.
- `cut -f2-` removes the date column from the output, leaving only the full paths.
- `tr '\n' '\0'` and `xargs -0 rm -r --` work as described above.